# In rails Label X and Y axis in chart. Implemented through chartkick and chart.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I want to keep label in my chart so that it will be descriptive. I have take reference of the chart from https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/155 but doesn't work for me.

My code in the view is  as:

```
               = line_chart @event_chart,discrete:true, legend: "bottom",curve: false,
           colors: ["#67b55e","#d43766","#729be0"],
          :library => {hAxis: {title: "months"}, vAxis: {title: "Y-label"}, title: "no. of events"}
```

My chart looks like:

[image: line chart]

Answer (score 1):

Through the  chartkick documentation I got the answer as:

```
 xtitle: "Time", ytitle: "Population"
```

adding line of code instead of library.